# how to get back to android activity page from webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

So if a logout button is clicked on the webview (which is a spring app), the page should get back to the android login page. is this possible? the code is on a .js file. i want it like

```
        if(btnlogout.clicked) then 
            go to Intent intent = new Intent(menuScreenActivity.this,
                        LoginActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm maybe yo need to integrate your webview and your java code as you can see here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Binding JavaScript code to Android code

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); 
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings(); 
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
```

So, you are Telling here that your webview can use run javascript and will be able to access  to your java code available at JavaScriptInterface class and its public methods on using js like this way:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

The line on javascript is **Android.showToast(toast);** and Android is the name you choosed here  **webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");**

**showToast** is a public method on JavaScriptInterface CLASS containing what ever you need, in this case:

```
**public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}**
```

just copied all this from that link... i think this answer your question, you can create your method called Logout that do the necesary stuff like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(menuScreenActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
```

Comment: youre welcome, if this is what you need then you can mark this as the answer xD

Comment: hi yardis, am working on a app where i will call webview for payment gateway and after payment in done, in webview there is a button. when user press that button i should collect some values and start a new android native activity.i think javascriptinterface is from getting return values javascript to webview. how can i return value from webview to native activity?