# VM aborting when starting new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I use the following link for [how to get back to android activity page from webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036375/how-to-get-back-to-android-activity-page-from-webview)

the solution works perfect to dispaly the Toast message only..

but here im facing issue is when try to start the new activity after the toast message im getting VM aborting error message.

```
public class JavaScriptInterface{
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        menuScreenActivity  menu=new menuScreenActivity ();
        menu.logout();//here i try to call the logut method
    }
}
```

in the menuScreenActivity Activity i created method called logout

Method in the menuScreenActivity

```
public void logout(){
      Intent myIntent= new Intent(menuScreenActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

My Log cat says

```
 JNI WARNING: jarray 0x405a2478 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
 "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058d718 self=0x1fecb0
  | sysTid=746 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=5148120
   | schedstat=( 23519331303 11309830622 1216 )
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:53)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1158)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
VM aborting
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`menuScreenActivity  menu=new menuScreenActivity ();` is almost certainly wrong.  You should never create and `Activity` with `new`.  It looks like you were doing that just to get a `Context` to pass to `Intent`.  You already have a `Context` you save a reference to, so you can use that to launch the intent, assuming you passed an Activity context.

```
/** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent myIntent= new Intent(mContext,LoginActivity.class);
        mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

Comment: @iagreen startActivity(myIntent); here im getting error as the method startActivity(myIntent) is undefined for the Type JavaScriptInterface

Comment: Is your javascriptInterface an inner class of an activity?

Comment: @iagreen no ya it is the separate class

Comment: When you instantiate the class, pass an `Activity` context and the above edit should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it normal that the `Intent` you create in the `logout()` method is called intent and you try to start the myIntent `Intent`?

Comment: do you have a MenuScreenActivity class and LoginActivity class too?

Answer (score 0):

You can change logout method to static in your menuScreenActivity,

```
public static logout(Context context){
  Intent myIntent= new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
  context.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

And then invoke the static method in JavaScriptInterface via,

```
menuScreenActivity.startActivity(mContext);
```

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity